# How to change permissions of a folder inside a container using docker run?

Tags: r, docker, shiny, shiny-server

I am running Shiny-Server (to run web applications built in R) in a Docker container. I have an application where user can upload some files. It's working, but on server OS I needed to give write and read permissions to the user "shiny". The problem is that everytime I need to do something with the container (like restart, or simply stop and start) I lose the change made on folder's permissions, which come back to default.

I tried to use `docker commit` and `docker run` again on container, using the new image, but it did not work. So now I am searching if I can use `docker run` and  `docker exec` togheter, doing something like this: `docker run <docker commands to run shiny-server> exec -it bash <bash commands to change folder permissions>`.

Is it possible? Does anyone has a good solution for this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile?  Are you setting permissions in the Dockerfile?

Comment: I changed the permission using `docker exec -it bash`, it is not in the Dockerfile. Doing this in the Dockerfile is the best way? Or can I change the permission when use `docker run`?

Comment: I suppose you could, but I would think it would be easier to maintain if it was in a Dockerfile and build directly into your image.  That would provide you with documentation, people that read the Dockerfile would see that a folder with particular permissions is constructed, and you wouldn't have to manually do the permission setup everytime you needed a new container.